# For traversing between rows of data frames to find frequency count of a variable

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

How to use for loop for traversing within rows of a dataframe.

I am writing code to find frequency of diamonds with color 'E'. But instead, I am getting frequency count of all rows. Here is the code snippet:

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame(diamonds)
cntx <- function() {
     cnt <- 0
     for(i in 1:nrow(dataframe1)) {
         if(dataframe1$color == "E") cnt <- cnt+1
     }
     return(cnt)
}
```

Comment: Your code was difficult to read because it wasn't indented properly.  I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I get the following warning from your code:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (dataframe1$color == "E") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The problem is that dataframe1$color is a vector of the length of the number of rows of dataframe1. You are comparing a vector of length x with a "vector" of length 1 ("E"). R thus only uses the first element of the boolean vector that results from the comparison. The first element appears to be "True". As the statement is always "True" it just counts every row.

How about the following?

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame(color = c("E", "F", "E", "F"))
sum(dataframe1$color == "E")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop in this case. Here are some ways to do it:

base R:

```
table(diamonds$color)
```

Hadleyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>%
   count(color)
```

If you insist on a loop:

```
cntx <- function(c){
  cnt <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(c)) {
    if (c$color[i] == "E") cnt <- cnt+1 #you forgot the i
    }
  return (cnt)
  }

cntx(diamonds)
```

You forgot the [i] in the loop so every time the whole `c$color == "E"` Boolean vector was computed and only the first element (which is T) was used for the evaluation hence the warnings:

```
1: In if (c$color == "E") cnt <- cnt + 1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and the result which was equivalent to the number of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there are a number of tools that can solve this problem with far fewer keystrokes.

My personal preference would be the `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
x <- as.data.table(diamonds)
x[color == "E",.N]
```

Returns the following

```
[1] 9797
```

More complicated queries require hardly any additional keystrokes.

```
x[,.(Count = .N), by = .(color)]
```

Returns

```
color   count
E       9797            
I       5422            
J       2808            
H       8304            
F       9542            
G       11292           
D       6775
```

or

```
x[price > 10000,.(carat = mean(carat)), by = .(color)]
```

Returns

```
color   carat
J       2.146045            
E       1.523220            
G       1.638468            
F       1.538835            
I       1.980648            
D       1.463780            
H       1.866069
```